# JavaScript, if-else shorthand better code

Tags: javascript

How can I do better this code:

```
let styleDaysCount = {'color': 'green'}
user.demo && user.days_count < 3 ? styleDaysCount = {'color': 'red'} : styleDaysCount = {'color': 'green'}
```

I want to remove the last `styleDaysCount = {'color': 'green'}` because I don't want a change in that condition
"When the user is demo and days_count are < 3, I need the style with color red"

I don't want to use:

```
let styleDaysCount = {'color': 'green'}
if (user.demo && (user.days_count < 3)) { styleDaysCount = {'color': 'red'} }
```

Comment: why you don't want to use `if` statement ?

Comment: Trying to get used with shorthand if-else. But I don't know if now is possible to have a shorter code with it.

Comment: it's called a `ternary operation`, FYI

Comment: Why do people hate if statements?

Comment: @pmiranda but this is not good case to use `ternary`, using shorthand may looks cool, but you should not try to put it everywhere

Comment: If you do not want it, then do not set it...

Comment: I don't hate it, but I catch a big proyect with almost zero if statements (React), I'm not very used to this "new" (to me) ternary operation, that's all.

Comment: `const styleDaysCount = { color: user.demo && user.days_count < 3 ? 'red' : 'green' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the conditional inside the object literal.

```
let styleDaysCount = {
    color: (user.demo && user.days_count < 3) ? 'red' : 'green'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do like that:

```
const color = user.demo && user.days_count < 3 ? 'red' : 'green';
const styleDaysCount = { color };
```

Comment: Why a vote down?

Comment: I wasn't, I just put vote up on what I find good, never vote down for a correct answer. Someone is voting down all the answers haha, even my question..

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the result from the ternary

```js
const styleDaysCount = user.demo && user.days_count < 3 ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': 'green'}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the functional implementation of if/else is very elegant and coincise:

**Implementation**

```
export const conditionally = (config) => (props) => {
  return config.if(props) ? 
    config.then(props) : config.else(props);
};
```

**Usage without functional if/else**

```
function getCarConfig(car) {
  let description;
  let newPrice;

  if (car.rating > 4) {
    description = "good car";
    newPrice = car.price + 1000 * car.rating;
  } else {
    description = "bad car";
    newPrice = car.price;
  }

  return {
    description,
    newPrice,
  }
}
```

**Usage with functional if/else**

```
const hasGoodRating = rating => rating > 4;

const priceChange = conditionally({
  if: hasGoodRating,
  then: rating => 1000 * rating,
  else: () => 1000,
});

const getDescription = conditionally({
  if: hasGoodRating,
  then: () => "good car",
  else: () => "bad car",
});

function getCarConfig (car) {
  return {
    newPrice: priceChange(car.rating) + car.price,
    description: getDescription(car.rating)
  }
}
```

Ref: https://itnext.io/if-else-and-try-catch-as-functional-constructs-da5c6a749f8c